# Using an existing query rather than a SELECT statement

Tags: c#, mysql

How do I use an existing query to pull in a recordset.  Currently, I am using SELECT statements such as this:

```
var com = new MySqlCommand("SELECT `Customer ID`, `Company Name`, `Address Line 3`, `Post Code`, `Serial No`, `Machine` FROM XText.all ORDER BY `Company Name`;") { Connection = _con, CommandType = CommandType.Text };
```

Ideally, I'd like to use something like:

```
var com = new MySqlCommand("XText.ExistingQueryHere") { Connection = _con, CommandType = CommandType.Text };
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you just trying to move the string to another location (e.g. resx file) or does "XText.ExistingQueryHere" represent something else?

Comment: You mean like calling a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand("XText.ExistingQueryHere", _con);

com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: Thank you guys (yet again) - really appreciated.